# AWS DMS Connection Issue: Test Endpoint Failure with Network Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I'm encountering an issue with AWS Data Migration Service (DMS) when I try to create either a source or a target endpoint. I receive the following error message:

```
"Test Endpoint failed: Application-Status: 1020912, Application-Message: Failed to connect Network error has occurred, Application-Detailed-Message: RetCode: SQL_ERROR SqlState: 08001 NativeError: 101 Message: timeout expired"
```

Here are the steps I've taken:

I set up a Replication Instance located in the same VPC as the endpoint.
The network ACL is set to the default, allowing connections. For testing purposes, I set the security groups for both inbound and outbound traffic to 0.0.0.0/0.
I tried various configurations of security groups. I attempted adding the DMS security group as a source for the RDS security group. I also tried using the exact private address. Regardless of these changes, including setting everything to 0.0.0.0/0, the connection to the endpoint fails.
The endpoint is a manually entered RDS PostgreSQL database, with the host, password, and port (5432) correctly specified.

I'm out of ideas and haven't found any solutions that seem to help with this issue. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Expected behavior is successful connection to aws dms service when i try to run test.

Answer (score 0):

When you added the inbound ruled for the DMS SG --> RDS, did it look similiar to the image below?

[image]